# How to efficiently a number from a list of numbers til 0

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I have an list of PTO object that has two properties AllowedHours and TakenHours.
I need to subtract PTO from the Accrued Banks until they hit 0 and then move to the next bank.

This code works but it looks off is there a way to do it more efficiently? Maybe a way to do it just through linq?

```
var requestedHours = requestDetail.Hours;
while (requestedHours > 0)
{
    var accrualBank = employeeAccruals.First(e => (e.AllowedHours - e.TakenHours) > 0);
    var hoursAvailable = accrualBank.AllowedHours - accrualBank.TakenHours;

    if (hoursAvailable > requestedHours)
    {
        accrualBank.TakenHours += requestedHours;
        requestedHours = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        accrualBank.TakenHours = accrualBank.AllowedHours;
        requestedHours -= hoursAvailable;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain us what you mean by "more efficiently". Do you mean faster code execution, less lines of code, lower consumption of power, or anything else that I forgot? According to what you mean by "efficiency", you'll (probably) get some answers. :-)

Comment: What is `employeeAccruals` - `List<SomeObject>`?

Comment: employeeAccruals is a the list of PTO accurals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a Linq candidate. In fact the only inefficient (from the performance perspective) part of your code is `employeeAccruals.First(...` inside the loop. The plain `for` loop will be the fastest, but I would suggest the following as being IMO the most balanced solution

```
foreach (var accrualBank in employeeAccruals)
{
    var takeHours = Math.Min(requestedHours, accrualBank.AllowedHours - accrualBank.TakenHours);
    accrualBank.TakenHours += takeHours;
    requestedHours -= takeHours;
    if (requestedHours == 0) break;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think about the foreach plus one